# DOM XML child nodes

Tags: php, xml, dom

If i have an XML for example like this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <parent >
     <child>
         <grandchild>
         </grandchild>
     </child> 
  </parent>
```

And i want to get all the children of the parent node (using php for example),
when i call

```
$xmlDoc->loadXML('..');

$rootNode = $xmlDoc->documentElement;

$children = $rootNode->childNodes;
```

what would `$children` contain?
Will it contain only `<child>` node ot will it contain `<child>` and `<grandchild>` both?

Comment: Try it and see... [here, for example](https://eval.in/374902): It contains 3 nodes, child and grandchild, and its content (text)

Comment: My output from dump is : 
`Outputs object(DOMNodeList)#3 (1) { ["length"]=> int(1) }` in eclipse and PHP 5.5. 
Then this means it gets only `<child>` node. Doesnt it?

Comment: `foreach ($rootNode->childNodes as $node) { echo $node->tagName, PHP_EOL; }` will tell you, other properties you can rely on include `nodeName` and `nodeType`... [see the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php)

Comment: I just tried it and it does not get grandchild, so if anone wants to get to `<grandchild>` should probably do it recursively.
I will post my answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `parent` document element node has 3 child nodes. The element node `child` and two text nodes containing the whitespaces before and after the node:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
foreach ($document->documentElement->childNodes as $childNode) {
  var_dump(get_class($childNode));
}
```

Output:

```
string(7) "DOMText"
string(10) "DOMElement"
string(7) "DOMText"
```

If you disable the preserve white space option on the document, it will remove the whitespace nodes while loading the xml.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$document->loadXml($xml);
...
```

Output:

```
string(10) "DOMElement"
```

To get nodes in a more flexible way use Xpath. It allows you to use expressions to fetch nodes:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/*/child|/*/child/grandchild') as $childNode) {
  var_dump(get_class($childNode), $childNode->localName);
}
```

Output:

```
string(10) "DOMElement"
string(5) "child"
string(10) "DOMElement"
string(10) "grandchild"
```